# CSS color of List item is not changing

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, css-specificity

I put a `class='active'` on the home list item:

[image]

Why doesn't it change its color?

```css
body {
  background: #000;
}
#wrapper {
  width: 68%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  /*border:1px solid #000;*/
  background: #fff;
  margin-top: 55px;
}
.container {
  padding: 20px;
  /*border:1px solid red;*/
  border-bottom: 3px solid #d6e1df;
}
#header {
  /*border:5px solid #4b9f52;*/
  padding: 0 100px 0 100px;
  text-align: center;
  font: 18px Josefin;
  color: #bbb;
  font-weight: 100;
  padding-top: 0;
}
#header h1 {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: #5d5d5d;
  /*border:1px solid #000;*/
}
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container>ul>li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
}
.container>ul>li>a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #bbb;
  padding: 10px;
}
.container>ul>li>a:hover {
  color: #3D9970;
  transition: 0.5s ease-out;
}
.active {
  color: red;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
#content {
  padding: 0 100px 0 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id='wrapper'>
  <div id='header'>
    <div class='container'>
      <h1>Chisinau</h1>
      <p>blog situat intre Prut si Nistru</p>
    </div>
    <div class='container'>
      <ul>
        <li><a class='active' href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Despre</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Cautare</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">En</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id='content'>
    <div class='container'>
      <h1>Post</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/3125ob13/)

Why doesn't it change? Do I need to change some code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because you have a more specific selector which is setting the color to the `a` element within `li`.

```
.container>ul>li>a{
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #bbb;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

The specificity of above selector is 013 because it has 1 class selector and 3 element type selectors as part of the complex selector chain. It has no id selector.

Because the `color: #bbb` is mentioned within this and the `.active` selector is less specific, the red color is not applied.

Change the selector for the `.active` class to be like below. This makes it more specific and thus will apply the color to the element.

```
.container>ul>li>a.active{
  color: red;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #000;
}
#wrapper {
  width: 68%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  /*border:1px solid #000;*/
  background: #fff;
  margin-top: 55px;
}
.container {
  padding: 20px;
  /*border:1px solid red;*/
  border-bottom: 3px solid #d6e1df;
}
#header {
  /*border:5px solid #4b9f52;*/
  padding: 0 100px 0 100px;
  text-align: center;
  font: 18px Josefin;
  color: #bbb;
  font-weight: 100;
  padding-top: 0;
}
#header h1 {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: #5d5d5d;
  /*border:1px solid #000;*/
}
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container>ul>li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
}
.container>ul>li>a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #bbb;
  padding: 10px;
}
.container>ul>li>a:hover {
  color: #3D9970;
  transition: 0.5s ease-out;
}
.container>ul>li>a.active{
  color: red;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
#content {
  padding: 0 100px 0 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id='wrapper'>
  <div id='header'>
    <div class='container'>
      <h1>Chisinau</h1>
      <p>blog situat intre Prut si Nistru</p>
    </div>
    <div class='container'>
      <ul>
        <li><a class='active' href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Despre</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Cautare</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">En</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id='content'>
    <div class='container'>
      <h1>Post</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The specificity of the modified selector is now 023 because it has one more class selector as part of the complex selector chain.

There is a very good specificity calculator that was built by Keegan Street and is available [here](https://specificity.keegan.st/). This is very useful till you get fully familiar with specificity calculations.

Comment: @Katallone: I added a solution also into the answer :)

Comment: +1 to your answer and OP I'll add that the least specificity a selector has, the better (as long as it does its job and doesn't style unwanted parts elsewhere, of course). Here, as `.container` matches both a heading and a navigation list, common practice is to add a second class like `.nav` to the div that only contains this list and then selectors as `.nav a` and `.nav .active` (specificities (0,1,1) and (0, 2, 0)) would do the job.

Comment: Valid point @FelipeAls. I just saw the CSS and didn't bother checking the HTML at all (or atleast not the parts outside of the nav) :D

Answer (score 0):

You can change active class like this

```
.active {
    border: 1px solid red;
    color: red !important;
}
```

Comment: Please don't advise anybody to add `!important` unless there is absolutely no other option. Adding `!important` is considered to be bad practice.